# comparing md5 hashing in android(java) and c#

Tags: c#, android, hash, md5

I am doing md-5 hashing in both android and c# at the same time. But both the results should be the same for the same inputs. Is there any difference in the way its done in both the languages?

I get different outputs in both the cases. Here is the c# code for md-5 calculation:

```
//this method hashes the values sent to it using MD5
public static String hashwithmd5(String toHashMD5)
{
    byte[] keyArray;

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toHashMD5));
    hashmd5.Clear();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(keyArray, 0, keyArray.Length); 
}
```

and here is the code for md5 in android using bouncycastle

```
public byte[] Hashing(String toHash) throws Exception{
    byte[] hashBytes = toHash.getBytes("UTF-8");
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
    org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.MD5Digest digest = new org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.MD5Digest();
    digest.reset();
    digest.update(hashBytes, 0, hashBytes.length);
    int length = digest.getDigestSize();
    byte[] md5 = new byte[length];
    digest.doFinal(md5, 0);
    et.setText(md5.toString());
    return md5;
}
```

the result of md5 in c# is :XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg==

the result of md5 in android is :[B@4053cf40

Comment: can somebody tell me what is different in two of these computations, and how I should change it to get the same o/p?

Comment: and what if you compare the byte arrays?  are they the same?

Comment: @cris can you get solution?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C# code converts the hash to Base64, the java code does not. If you convert both raw hashes to e.g. hex strings, they'll be the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this in Java:

```
byte[] md5 = new byte[length];
// ...
md5.toString()
```

you are *not* getting a representation of the byte values. You get the generic "string representation" of an object. Here, `[B@4053cf40` basically means "array of bytes (that's for the '[B') which internally happens to be at address 4053cf40".

Use `android.util.Base64` to convert your bytes to a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how this library android.util.Base64 is used to convert a byte array into a base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

@erik is correct.  MD5 is no longer considered a "secure" hash; use SHA-256.

Answer (score 0):

Erik is absolutely right. MD5 usage is near extinction, use any strong SHA